# Jest simulate offline network with Mock Service Worker (MSW) or other?

Tags: jestjs, msw

Is it possible to use MSW with Jest to simulate offline network conditions? Alternatively non MSW based solutions would suffice. I also don't want to mock `navigator.onLine` as I want to test the error path when a network request fails due to being offline.

Comment: Why not? Jest runs in Node environment. It doesn't care about networking. If you can run MSW in Node, you can use it. Did you check https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/node ?

Comment: Sure I know MSW runs in jest I'm trying to determine how to simulate an offline network?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can simulate a network error:

```js
rest.get('/user', (_, res) => {
  return res.networkError('Custom network error message')
})
```

Here is the related documentation: https://mswjs.io/docs/api/response/network-error

Comment: This is the recommended way to do it: network error is an equivalent of an error that happens when requesting a resource being offline.